# checking to see if a text box is empty in php

Tags: php, html

I have a php/html from where the user enters a number of values which are then updated into a database by using mysqli and a insert query, If the user does not enter anything into any of the text boxes I want a message to appear saying that the information is not there, I have tried using

```
if($ownerName == "" ){
    echo("Missing Information!");
```

but it won't work.

Here is my php code

```html
<?php

include "connect.php";
if($_POST["submit"])
{
    $ownerName = $_POST['OwnerName'];
    $location = $_POST['Location'];
    $phoneNumber = $_POST['PhoneNumber'];

   if($ownerName == "" || $location == "" || $phoneNumber == ""){
    echo("Missing Information!");

    /*if(is_numeric($phoneNumber) ){
                        settype($phoneNumber, "integer");
            }*/
 

    $query = "INSERT INTO OWNER VALUES ('$ownerName','$location', $phoneNumber)";




    if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('1 record added')</script>";
    

    mysqli_close($con); 
}
?>
```

Here is my form

```html
<html><head><title>Connect to Database</title></head><body> 

<font size="4"> Enter owner details</font><br><br> 
<form action="update.php" method="post" >

Owner Name:<input  type="text" name="OwnerName"> 
Location: <input  type="text" name="Location"> 
Phone Number:<input  type="text" name="PhoneNumber"> 
<input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Submit Value"> 
</form></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    include "connect.php";
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $ownerName = isset($_POST['OwnerName']) ? $_POST['OwnerName']: '';
        $location =  isset($_POST['Location']) ? $_POST['Location']: '';
        $phoneNumber = isset($_POST['PhoneNumber']) ? $_POST['PhoneNumber']: '';

        //preventing sql injection
        /*
          $ownerName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $ownerName);
          $$location = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $ownerName);
          $$phoneNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $ownerName);
         */

        if(empty($ownerName) || empty($location) || empty($phoneNumber)){
            echo("Missing Information!");

            /*if(is_numeric($phoneNumber) ){
             settype($phoneNumber, "integer");
             }*/


        }else{
            $query = "INSERT INTO OWNER VALUES ('$ownerName','$location', $phoneNumber)";




            if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('1 record added')</script>";
        }
         mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Also try using var_dump($_POST) to see what is sent.

**EDIT:**

I've updated if/else statement so now it should work. Also, make sure you have your error reporting enabled:

```
<?php
// Turn off error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report runtime errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
?>
```

Comment: sadly no luck with this, after I click submit a blank page (white screen) appears

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
if((!isset($ownerName)) || $ownerName == "" || (!isset($location)) || $location == "" || (!isset($phoneNumber)) || $phoneNumber == "")){
    echo("Missing Information!");

    /*if(is_numeric($phoneNumber) ){
                        settype($phoneNumber, "integer");
            }*/

}
    else{
    $query = "INSERT INTO OWNER VALUES ('$ownerName','$location', $phoneNumber)";




if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('1 record added')</script>";


mysqli_close($con); 

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

Change  your condtion from

```
 if($ownerName == "" || $location == "" || $phoneNumber == ""){
    echo("Missing Information!");
$query = "INSERT INTO OWNER VALUES ('$ownerName','$location', $phoneNumber)";




    if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('1 record added')</script>";


    mysqli_close($con); 
}
```

to

```
 if($ownerName == "" || $location == "" || $phoneNumber == ""){
    echo("Missing Information!");
    } else {
$query = "INSERT INTO OWNER VALUES ('$ownerName','$location', $phoneNumber)";




    if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('1 record added')</script>";


    mysqli_close($con); 
}
```

Comment: still no luck with this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<?php

include "connect.php";
if($_POST["submit"])
{
    $ownerName = $_POST['OwnerName'];
    $location = $_POST['Location'];
    $phoneNumber = $_POST['PhoneNumber'];}

   if(empty($ownerName) && empty($location) && empty($phoneNumber))

{
    echo("Missing Information!");}

    /*if(is_numeric($phoneNumber) ){
                        settype($phoneNumber, "integer");
            }*/
 


else{
    $query = "INSERT INTO OWNER VALUES ('$ownerName','$location', $phoneNumber)";




    if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('1 record added')</script>";
    

    mysqli_close($con); 
}
?>
```

Comment: I think the problem is elsewhere!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `empty()` function or `isset()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

include "connect.php";
if($_POST["submit"])
{
 $ownerName = $_POST['OwnerName'];
 $location = $_POST['Location'];
 $phoneNumber = $_POST['PhoneNumber'];

 if($ownerName == "" || $location == "" || $phoneNumber == ""){
   echo("Missing Information!");
 }
 else{

 $query = "INSERT INTO OWNER VALUES ('$ownerName','$location',  $phoneNumber)";

   if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
   {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
   }
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('1 record added')</script>";
 }
  mysqli_close($con); 
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Please replace your code from below code**
<?php

    include "connect.php";

    if($_POST["submit"])
    {
        $ownerName  = $_POST['OwnerName'];
        $location   = $_POST['Location'];
        $phoneNumber    = $_POST['PhoneNumber'];

        if($ownerName == "" || $location == "" || $phoneNumber == ""){
            echo("Missing Information!");
        } else {
            // please replace your column name (`owner_name`, `location`, `phone_number`) 
            $query = "INSERT INTO OWNER (`owner_name`, `location`, `phone`) VALUES ('" . $ownerName . "', '" . $location. "', " . $phoneNumber. ")";

            if (!mysqli_query($con, $query))
            {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('1 record added')</script>";

            mysqli_close($con); 

        }
    }
    ?>
```